# How do I contribute a command to the VS Code explorer title bar or command palette that is only active when my webview is focused?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing an extension that uses VS Code's [webview api](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview). My extension also registers a `refresh preview` command that updates the webview's content.  How can I make it so that:

- The `refresh preview` command only shows up in the command palette when my webview is focused?
- The `refresh preview` command shows in the webview's editor title bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create a custom [context key](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts) that tracks when your webview is focused. Use VS Code's `setContext` command to make this context key track when your webview is focused:

```ts
const myWebview = ...;

// Make the context key track when one of your webviews is focused
myWebview.onDidChangeViewState(({ webviewPanel }) => {
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext',
        'myWebviewFocused',
        webviewPanel.active);
});
```

Then use your context key in the `when` clauses of your extension's [menus contribution point](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus)

For a command with the id `myExtension.refreshPreview`, to ensure that command only shows up in the command palette when your webview is focused, use the following contribution:

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "menus": {
      "commandPalette": [
        {
          "command": "myExtension.refreshPreview",
          "when": "myWebviewFocused",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For adding a command (possible with icon) to the editor title bar of your webview, use the `editor/title` contribution point:

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "menus": {
      "editor/title": [
        {
          "command": "myExtension.refreshPreview",
          "when": "myWebviewFocused",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Check out [VS Code's built-in markdown extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/markdown-language-features) for a more advanced example of this.