# (VSCode): Hide views when file type exists in workspace

Tags: view, visual-studio-code, visibility, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VSCode extension and would only like a `viewContainer` to be visible if the workspace has a file with a given extension. It seems if all views in a `viewContainer` are hidden, it will be hidden as well. I added `"when"` clauses in `package.json` to hide the views accordingly. The issue is that these "when" clauses can only seem to check for when a selected item in the explorer has a certain filename/extension, or when an editor is open with a filename/extension. I see no variable to check if a workspace has a given file/language.

The ultimate goal is for my extension's `viewContainer` needs to disappear if the workspace does not have the relevant file types the extension was made for. Asking the user to have one of the files open/selected at all times to have the extension visible is not ideal.

If this is not possible, it would be nice if someone could recommend an alternative approach that allows me to hide the `viewContainer` in an intuitive way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I contribute a command to the VS Code explorer title bar or command palette that is only active when my webview is focused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54917748/how-do-i-contribute-a-command-to-the-vs-code-explorer-title-bar-or-command-palet)

Comment: ^That answer shows how to set custom `when` variables using `setContext`.