# Vscode Ext display extension only when project have some file

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've created a vscode extension which handle some `Rakefile` tasks.
Now I want to limit that the extension will be displayed in the explorer only when user
open a `Rakefile`

for that I use the following entry in the package.json

```
 "contributes": {
    "views": {
      "explorer": [
        {
          "id": "rakeView",
          "name": "Rakee",
          "when": "resourceFilename ='Rakefile'"
        }
      ]
    },
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "rakeView.executeTask",
        "title": "Execute",
        "icon": "images/icon.png"
      }
    ],
```

when adding the following line

```
"when": "resourceFilename ='Rakefile'"
```

the extension removed from the explorer view, when I remove it I was able to see the extension.
I want it to display only when a project have a `Rakefile` how could I do it ?

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/1aae138e311fb87cc3ed2782be287f5d2f78e327/task-provider-sample

**update**

After trying the answer below it's still **not working**, this is the all code:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import { rakeTaskProvider } from "./rakeCmd";
import { TaskTreeDataProvider } from "./rakeView";

let rakeTaskProvider: vscode.Disposable | undefined;

export function activate(_context: vscode.ExtensionContext): void {
  const workspaceRoot = vscode.workspace.rootPath;

  const onChangeActiveTextEditor = () => {
    let editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'rakeView:fileIsRake', editor && editor.document.languageId === 'rakefile');
  };
  vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(onChangeActiveTextEditor, null, _context.subscriptions);
  onChangeActiveTextEditor();

  rakeTaskProvider = vscode.tasks.registerTaskProvider(
    rakeTaskProvider.rakeType,
    new rakeTaskProvider(workspaceRoot)
  );
  vscode.window.registerTreeDataProvider(
    "rakeView",
    new TaskTreeDataProvider(_context)
  );
  vscode.commands.registerCommand("rakeView.executeTask", function (task) {
    console.log(task);
    vscode.tasks.executeTask(task).then(
      function (value) {
        return value;
      },
      function (e) {
        console.error(
          "error",
          e
        );
      }
    );
  });
}

export function deactivate(): void {
  if (rakeTaskProvider) {
    rakeTaskProvider.dispose();
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"contributes": {
    "views": {
      "explorer": [
        {
          "id": "rakeView",
          "name": "Rakke",
          "when": "rakeView:fileIsRake"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Comment: you are inconsistent `only when user open a Rakefile` and `only when a project have a Rakefile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the context, when the editor changes set a context variable to signal the current file is a Rakefile

In your `activate` function

```javascript
  const onChangeActiveTextEditor = () => {
    let editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'myExtenstion:fileIsRake', editor && editor.document.languageId === 'rake');
  };
  vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(onChangeActiveTextEditor, null, context.subscriptions);
  onChangeActiveTextEditor();
```

In `package.json` add this context variable

```
    "views": {
      "explorer": [
        {
          "id": "rakeView",
          "name": "Rakee",
          "when": "myExtenstion:fileIsRake"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, what it the "myExtension" ?is it the package.json name property?

Comment: @BenoOdr `myExtension` is just the name of your extension, to find the correct languageId log the languageId to the console

Comment: thanks, its not working, could you please take a look at the update and see what im missing here?

Comment: @BenoOdr What is the languageId for Rake files use a`console.log` in the extension to find out

Comment: console.log to what? in addition my code looks ok and the package json

Comment: @BenoOdr If you put a `console.log` in the extension and debug the extension the log will appear in the host VSC, if the language id does not match the context var will never be true

Comment: yes I know that :) I mean to find hte languate id? does the code looks right?

Comment: btw, its `rakefile` , but still when changing it its not working

Comment: when you force the context variable to be `true` or `false` does the view show/hide, I use this method in my extension for HTML files and it works

Comment: sorry, where should I put it?

Comment: @BenoOdr `vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'rakeView:fileIsRake', true);`

Comment: still I dont see it, any other idea?

Comment: if I remove the `"when": "rakeView:fileIsRake"`, I was able to see it (always) but for all type of projects, even If I dont have the rakefile

Comment: @BenoOdr you want to see the view when there is a `Rakefile` in the workspace, even when it is not in any editor

Comment: yes if user open a folder which have rakefile I want to see it, any project

Comment: @BenoOdr This answer shows the view when the CURRENT file is a rakefile, Change the setting of the context variable whenever the extension is activated and search the workspace for the `rakefile`

Comment: this is doesnt work either when I open a rakefile:( , anyway in case that I want to change it that when I open a project folder which contain a rakefile how should I do it?

Comment: @BenoOdr What is the LanguageId in the lower right Status bar of VSc when you have a rakefile open, for that file log the LanguageId and use it in the code

Comment: Is it just `"when": "fileIsRake"`?  From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54917748/how-do-i-contribute-a-command-to-the-vs-code-explorer-title-bar-or-command-palet  Or does it not make any difference?

Comment: @Mark You need to use the exact same name as used in the `setContext` call, your link does not have the extension name in the context variable, this gives the possibility of name clashes

Comment: @rioV8 - the name is Rakefile, I've change it and still I dont see it..., btw, I want something as the npm task expolrer, when you open a nodejs project which have package.json you can see it in the task explorer , if you dont have it , you will not see it

Comment: @BenoOdr What do you mean with `npm task explorer`? Just change the `setContext` call to a true/false if there is a file `workspaceFolder/Rakefile`, see the extension sample on how to find the Rakefiles